# Storing .css() method in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, methods

I've Googled my face off with no luck including searching this site. I just want a simple clear answer.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div id="main-navigation">  
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Here is the css method I'm using which I've tested and works:**

```
// Layout 1
$('#default').click(function() {
    if('true' == 'true') {
        // General Values
        $(hmnavUL).css({ backgroundColor: bgDefault });
});
```

**Here is the variable I've created:**

```
var bgSet = $(hmnavUL).css({ backgroundColor: bgDefault });
```

**Here is what I'm trying to achieve:**

```
// Layout 1
$('#default').click(function() {
    if('true' == 'true') {
        // General Values
        bgSet
});
```

**The result:**

The Browser completely ignores my "bgSet" variable, but it acknowledges the style when I don't use a variable. It's not giving me any errors either with my preferred version. Anything you can tell me about my syntax would be appreciated. I'm assuming it's my syntax.

I've linked a photo example to demonstrate the my desired end product (note: I can't attach images yet).

(Default Layout, Second Layout, Remove All Styles)

Desired result: [Result](http://wissingerdesigns.com/mdztr/change-styles-test/images.html)

Comment: `bgSet` is a jQuery object since you are using `.css()` as a setter when you declare `bgSet`. What are you expecting it to be?

Comment: Your comment wasn't really helpful but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to toggle and element's css properties based on `click` eventHandler. You've got the right idea, but you're javascript is slightly off. Here's an example that should perform the function you want:

```js
// Function to change the css of an element
function makeRed(elem){
    elem.css({ "background-color" : "red" });
};

// Attach an event handler..
$("#clickMe").click(function(){

    // Store the object as a variable
    var obj = $("#foo"); // <-- The element you want to change the bg of
    
    // Run your function.
    makeRed(obj);
    
});
```

```css
#foo{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div><br />
<button id="clickMe">Click Me!</button>
```

This is really about learning how javascript selectors, functions and variables work.. Although your question is phrased in a sort-of obtuse way for StackOverflow, I appreciate that you posted your code and that you're trying to learn. :)

Comment: I just read your last comment. I didn't mean to be obtuse. I am new to JS and wanted to make sure I was clear as to what I wanted. I almost never find helpful answers on this site because your vocabularies are beyond me lol.

Comment: Obtuse was definitely harsher than intended - sorry for that :). I don't think you should have gotten "downvoted" since you posted your code and (IMO) it showed that you were new to js, trying to learn and using a practical example to figure things out rather than reading through a tutorial. For js related questions, a good rule of thumb is: Post code that can be quickly rerun in a sandbox (or SO snippet) like http://jsfiddle.net/. Best.

Answer (score 2):

The variable doesn't contain what you expect it to do. The code isn't kept in the variable, it's executed right away and the return value from the `css` method (which is the jQuery object) is stored in the variable.

You can't put a "macro" in a variable and have it executed by referencing the variable. The closest thing to what you are trying to do would be to put the code in a function, so that it can be executed later:

```
var bgSet = function() {
  $(hmnavUL).css({ backgroundColor: bgDefault });
});

// Layout 1
$('#default').click(function() {
  if('true' == 'true') {
    // General Values
    bgSet();
  }
});
```